Extending a local property of a measure to a global property of the measure.
Let $\mu_1$ be an outer measure, $\mu_2$ be a measure, and $E$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Suppose that for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$, there exists a neighborhood of $V_x$ of $x$ such that $$\mu_1(E\cap V_x)\le \mu_2(E\cap V_x).$$
Is it true that
$$\mu_1(E)\le\mu_2(E)?$$
I hope this statement is true. This is my attempt at proving this:
Since $E$ is bounded, it is contained in a cube $[0,R]^d$. We have that $\bigcup_{x\in [0,R]^d}V_x$ is an open cover of $[0,R]^d$ which has a finite subcover $V_{x_1},...,V_{x_N}$. Thus,
$$\mu_1(E)=\mu_1\left(E\cap \bigcup_{i=1}^NV_{x_i}\right)$$
and
$$\mu_2(E)=\mu_2\left(E\cap \bigcup_{i=1}^NV_{x_i}\right).$$
If the $V_{x_i}'s$ are disjoint, then
$$\begin{aligned}\mu_1(E)~&=~\mu_1\left(E\cap \bigcup_{i=1}^NV_{x_i}\right)~\le~\sum_{i=1}^N\mu_1\left(E\cap V_{x_i}\right)\\&\le~\sum_{i=1}^N\mu_2\left(E\cap V_{x_i}\right)=\mu_2\left(E\cap \bigcup_{i=1}^NV_{x_i}\right)=\mu_2(E).\end{aligned}$$
The issue is that in general, the $V_{x_i}'s$ are not disjoint. I am thinking of fixing $\varepsilon>0$ and choosing $V_{x_i^\varepsilon}$, $i=1,...,N_\varepsilon$ such that the overlap $$\sum_{i=1}^{N_\varepsilon}\mu_2\left(E\cap V_{x_i^\varepsilon}\right)-\mu_2\left(E\cap \bigcup_{i=1}^{N_\varepsilon}V_{x_i^\varepsilon}\right)~\le~\varepsilon.$$ Taking $\varepsilon\to0$ this would complete the proof. I'm not sure how to determine $V_{x_i}^\varepsilon$, though, or if there is another approach I could use.

Edit: It is not true in general. My first example (copied verbatim at the end of this posting) had a major problem. Here is a fix in the same spirit:
Let $\mu_1=\frac12(\delta_{-1}+\delta_1)+\frac12\delta_0$ and $\mu_2=\delta_0+\frac14(\delta_{-2}+\delta_{2})$. For $E=\{-1,0,1\}$
$\mu_1(E)=3/2>\mu_2(E)=1$.

If $x=0$, let $B_x=(-1/2,1/2)$ so that $E\cap B_x=\{0\}$ and $\mu_1(\{0\})=1/2<\mu_2(\{0\})=1$;
if $x=1$, let $B_x=(-1/2,3/2)$ so that $E\cap B_x=\{0,1\}$ and $\mu_1(\{0,1\})=1=\mu_2(\{0,1\})$;
if $x=-1$ let $B_x=(-3/2,1/2)$ so that $E\cap B_x=\{-1,0\}$ and $\mu_1(\{-1,0\})=1=\mu_2(\{0,1\})$;
if $x\notin E$, choose $r>0$ small enough so that $(x-r,x+r)\cap E=\emptyset$.

The choice of the atomic measures $\delta_{\pm2}$ is just so that $\mu_1(\mathbb{R})=\mu_2(\mathbb{R})<\infty$.


(original example) Consider the measures $\mu_1=\frac14\delta_0+\frac34\delta_1$ and $\mu_2=\frac12(\delta_0+\delta_2)$. Let $E=\{0,1\}$. Every point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ has a neighborhood $B_x$ such that $\mu_1(E\cap B_x)\leq \mu_2(E\cap B_x)$ however, $\mu_1(E)=1>\mu_2(E)=\frac12$.


Inspired by Mittens' answer, I came up with the following. Let $\mu_1$ be the Lebesgue measure, $\mu_2 = \delta_0$ and $E = [-1,1]$. For $x > 0$, you can use $V_x = (0, \infty)$ and likewise for $x < 0$. For $x = 0$, one takes $(-1/2, 1/2)$.

$(0, \infty)$ doesn't work for $x > 0$, but $\left( x - \frac{1}{4}, x+\frac{1}{4} \right) \cup \left( -\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4} \right)$ works for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I think I was thinking of $[0,\infty)$ (if you allow for neighborhoods to be non-open).

Right, that works too.
